# How do I convert integer to 4-digit hex string?

Tags: vb.net, vba

I need to convert a 2-byte signed integer into a string of it's hex equivalent, but I need the string to be 4 characters.  I've tried the Hex() function but when I convert 0 or say, 10, the result is 0 or A.  I need the result to be 0000 or 000A.  Any tips or advice?

Answer (score 8):

It is just

```
 Dim hexS As String = i.ToString("X4")
```

This is well explained in the [The Hexadecimal (X) Format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#XFormatString).
The 4 after the X specifies how many chars you want in the output and if there are not enough chars, the missing ones are supplied as an appropriate number of "0".

Answer (score 3):

Since you also tagged the question `VBA`, here is a VBA way to do it

```
Right("0000" & Hex(i), 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
    Dim i As Integer = 10
    Dim hexS As String = i.ToString("X4")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are deadset on using `Hex` as opposed to string formatting then you could use:

```
Dim Number As Integer
Dim Output As String

Number = 10
Output = ("000" & Hex(Number))
Output = Output.Substring(Output.Length - 4, 4)
Console.WriteLine(Output)
```

Alternatively make use of string formatting for numbers as so:

```
Output = Number.ToString("X4")
Console.WriteLine(Output)
```

The output in both cases with be `000A`.

Answer (score 0):

The VB way

```
Format(i, "X4")
```

or

```
Hex(i).PadLeft(4, "0"c)
```

In Visual Studio 2015:

```
s = $"{i:X4}"
```